# Can you use 2 recycler views from one adapter with android? or how can i display two recyclerviews

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have made an app that pulls data from a phpMyAdmin database and displays it fine in a recyclerview using an adapter. It is a fitness app that displays a log of workouts completed, and also a gallery of images the user has uploaded.

Now what I want to do, is have the workouts in one activity using a recycler view, and a gallery of photos in another activity also using a recycler view.

I have a dataclass file set up to get all the data from the database using an API and it works fine for the activity showing the workouts, using a recyclerview layout, adapter and interface.

I've set up another adaptor for the pictures activity it is saying recycler view cannot be null? and not working

I'm coding in Kotlin.

code for workout adaptor

```
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
        import android.view.View
        import android.view.ViewGroup
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.workout_layout.view.*
        class WorkoutAdapter(
        private val workouts: List<api>
        ) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkoutAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.workout_layout, parent, false))
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val theWorkout = workouts.get(position)
        holder.workoutName.text = theWorkout.workoutName
        holder.workoutDesc.text = theWorkout.workoutDesc
        holder.workoutDate.text = theWorkout.workoutDate


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return workouts.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val workoutName = view.txtWorkoutName
        val workoutDesc = view.txtWorkoutDesc
        val workoutDate = view.txtWorkoutDate

    }

}
```

and code for picture adapter

```
    class galleryAdapter (

    private val images: List<api>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<galleryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_gallery_layout, parent, false))
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val theImage = images.get(position)

        Picasso.get().load(theImage.image).
        into(holder.userImage)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return images.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val userImage = view.progressPicture
    }


}
```

this is the code im using for the gallery activity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_gallery_layout.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

 class galleryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_layout)
loadData()
}

private fun loadData() {
    val service  = ServiceBuilder.buildService(WorkoutService::class.java)
    val requestCall = service.getWorkout()

    requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<api>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<api>>,
                                response: Response<List<api>>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                //process data

                recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@galleryActivity)
                recyclerView.adapter = galleryAdapter(response.body()!!)

            }else{
                //output alert
                AlertDialog.Builder(this@galleryActivity)
                    .setTitle("API error")
                    .setMessage("Response, but something went wrong ${response.message()}")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show()

            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<api>>, t: Throwable) {
            //process failure
            AlertDialog.Builder(this@galleryActivity)
                .setTitle("API error")
                .setMessage("No response, and something went wrong $t")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show()



           }
        })
    }

}
```

workout activity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.workout_layout.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class workoutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadData()

    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val service  = ServiceBuilder.buildService(WorkoutService::class.java)
        val requestCall = service.getWorkout()

        requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<api>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<api>>,
                                    response: Response<List<api>>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    //process data
                    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@workoutActivity,)
                    recyclerView.adapter = WorkoutAdapter(response.body()!!)

                }else{
                    //output alert
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this@workoutActivity)
                        .setTitle("API error")
                        .setMessage("Response, but something went wrong ${response.message()}")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show()

                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<api>>, t: Throwable) {
                //process failure
                AlertDialog.Builder(this@workoutActivity)
                    .setTitle("API error")
                    .setMessage("No response, and something went wrong $t")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show()

            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am a but confused about your question, is it about using one adapter with 2 recycler views or about the error you've received?

Comment: You shared your Activity code twice and missed sharing your adapter code. Anyway, this is a risky way of handling this, because if the data arrives after the Activity is closed, the synthetic properties will give you null and crash the app. Migrate to view binding and I suggest using coroutines for easy automatic cancellation of your network request when the activity is closed.

Comment: thanks! code all sorted in the post now, sorry its my first post, the question is about if i can use 1 adaptor with two views or if there is another way of doing it? As you can see in the code, I've tried making two adapters but it doesnt work, not sure if I'm missing something, I'm new to android studio and kotlin